# Stuck with spawning objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject

I'm making a 'run' game in Unity and I'm making a prototype with a ball, that has other balls following him. If the followers hit an object they get destroyed after some time. To make it so you don't run out of enemies I made a trigger that spawns new enemies. In the code this is the function `Addzombies`.

1. How do I make them spawn not on the same point, if i run it now they
   start on eachother and bounce around as an explosion.
2. How do i make some start in the air, i tried it but they don't
   spawn.

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

    public float InputForce;
    public GUIText guiText;
    public float rotationHorizontal;
    public AudioClip ACeffect2;
    public GameObject zombiePrefab;

    void FixedUpdate() {

        rigidbody.AddForce( Camera.main.transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * InputForce);
        rigidbody.AddForce( Camera.main.transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * InputForce);

        transform.position += Vector3.forward *InputForce * Time.deltaTime;
        rotationHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * InputForce;
        rotationHorizontal *= Time.deltaTime;
        rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.back * rotationHorizontal);

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Zombie") {
            Debug.Log ("Player geraakt, nu ben je eigenlijk dood");
        }
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Obstakel1") {
            Debug.Log ("Obstakel1 geraakt");
            audio.PlayOneShot(ACeffect2);
            InputForce = 0;
        }
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Obstakel2") {
            Debug.Log ("Obstakel2 geraakt");
        }
    }

    void AddZombies(int aantal){
        for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++){
            GameObject go = GameObject.Instantiate(zombiePrefab, transform.position - new Vector3(0, 0, 7 + i),Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            Zombie zb = go.GetComponent<Zombie>();
            zb.target = gameObject.transform;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
        Debug.Log ("Enter" +col.name);
        if (col.tag == "AddZombies"){
            AddZombies(4);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col) {
        Debug.Log ("Leaving with" +col.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do mean by start on each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will advice on how things could be done, but you will have to make changes to make it suit your requirement

```
public Transform zombiePrefab; // From the editor drag and drop your prefab


void addZombies()
{   
    // as you need them to be not on the same point
    int randomX = Random.Range(-10.0F, 10.0F);
    for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++){
        // make a transform
        var zombieTransform = Instantiate(zombiePrefab) as Transform; 
        zombieTransform.position = new Vector3(randomX, 0, 7 + i);
        transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().enabled = false;            
        // make it enable when you need and add force to make them fall     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing the number of zombies to pass, and an integer representing the range of space that they can spawn in. Then just use UnityEngine.Random with said integer for each zombie to produce several different co-ordinates for spawning the zombies.

As for getting them to spawn in the air, just increase the y co-ordinate when you instantiate the zombie.